# How to know Which Firebase Remote Config parameter was published

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

Lets say I have 50 Remote Config parameters in the Firebase console and I change one. Then I press the publish changes button right.

On Android client side when doing `firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();`is there a way to see what exactly was changed or must I iterate over all 50 parameters and test them?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know what has changed. I think you should just apply the changes with the new parameters. If you want more complex behaviour, then you should probably use the Realtime database with the RecyclerView that updates only what has changed.

Comment: I'm curious what your use-case is here. Is this just for debugging purposes? Or are you trying to avoid, say, some expensive layout calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "diff" function or anything with remote config where you can see what's changed. If you're actually curious as to what's changed since the last time you retrieved data, you'd need to iterate over all of your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way on the Android client side to check the diff unless you store the previous version and do the diff manually on your side. However,
Firebase remote config does provide diff option now. Go to Firebase remote config and do the following:

[image]

Click on the history icon next to the Add Parameter button it will show something like the following:
[image]

Select an item in the history to from which you want to see the diff and then on the other item, hover your mouse curser and location the 3 dotes menu and select compare with selected version.

Firebase will show you the diff and you can choose for show differences only option to see the changed item alone.
[image]

Note: I could not find the whole value diff even after coming to this stage of diff. If you config value json is long and then you can not really see the whole difference. It would have been better if Firebase had provided complete diff option.